# WP search exclude last letter from string

Tags: query, hooks

i need to exclude last letter from search string, because WP search is word sensitive.

I mean the situations like user entered word "dogs" but in titles i have no dogs, i have "dog". In this case user gets 0 results, but if we filtered search string and remove last letter, before sending search results user gets results from "dog".

Code is simple

```
$word = substr($word, 0, -1);
```

Where $word is a search string. But i can't find a hook. Is there any filter or hook, or where is processing search string file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`get_search_query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_search_query/) filter.

```
function mySearchFunction($search_term){

    $search_term = substr($search_term, 0, -1);

    return $search_term;

}

add_filter('get_search_query','mySearchFunction');
```

**EDIT**

Action to filter query results:

```
function mySearchFilterFunction($query) {

 if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_search) {

    $search_term = $query->get('s');
    $query->set('s', substr($search_term, 0, -1));

 }

}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'mySearchFilterFunction');
```

[`get_search_query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_search_query/) filter is not needed because it uses `get_query_var( 's' )` which is modified by our `pre_get_posts` action.

Comment: Works not as expected, it doesn't remove last character, but doesn't display in template "Search for  get_search_query()", where get_search_query() is a search string

Comment: What do you mean is not working? You asked for a hook and this is the hook processing the search term.

Comment: @AlexPain Sorry, I didn't understood that you need to modify the search results also. I update my answer.

Comment: Sory, but not working. Yes, i'm looking for hook, but pre_get_posts or get_search_query don't work. I need to exclude last character before i get results

Comment: Of course i can make it by jquery, but i think in this way maybe right to do it with php

Comment: @AlexPain I tested on my localhost and is working fine. What do you mean by is not working?

Comment: Maybe it is important, i don't know, but my site is on russian language. I try it with english word, works, but in url /?s= value doesn't changes. In Russian in url is my search full word and is empty parameter get_search_query()